# TSQL join over 4 tables with exclude condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm currently working on a query on SQL Server 2014. I try to do a join over 4 tables with an exclude condition in the table [table_ad_attribute].[FK_attribute] = 42.

The tables are always connected, PK_ID = FK_Tablename :

```
SELECT [A].PK_ID, [B].Surname, [B].Firstname
FROM [dbo].[client] [A]

INNER JOIN [dbo].[contact] [B]
   ON [B].FK_Client = [A].PK_ID
  AND [A].Type = 22

// i assume this join is wrong
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ad] [C]
   ON [C].FK_Client = [A].PK_ID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[table_ad_attribute] [D]
   ON [D].FK_ad = [C].PK_ID 
  AND [D].FK_attribute = 42
```

The problem is, I'm getting an **endless loop** when I execute my query. It takes a long time to execute and shows a lot of entries several times. I think it's because of the 2nd inner join. Maybe i should use another join type?

Some sample data:

**dbo.client**

```
PK_ID | Type
-------------
 1    |  22
 2    |  33
```

**dbo.contact**

```
PK_ID | FK_Client | Surname | Lastname
---------------------------------------
 12   |  1        | Doe     | John
```

**dbo.ad**

```
PK_ID | FK_Client
-----------------
 54   |  1
```

**dbo.table_ad_attribute**

```
FK_ad | FK_attribute
---------------------
 54   |   42
```

*Desired output:*

```
PK_ID | Surname | Firstname
---------------------------
  1   | Doe     | John
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? Perhaps which join to take in this scenario?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what you mean endless loop? slow? do you have index? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: i takes very long to execute and shows each entry several times. i think i have an issue with my join type...

Comment: You provided the desired output, but can you provide the current output you are getting? I'm thinking you can change your inner joins to left joins but I can't tell without seeing the "bad" output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining [A] -> [B] to get your result columns.

You're also joining [A] -> [C] -> [D] to get your filter.

I think what's happening is that your filter is returning multiple instances of each of your [A].PK_ID values so you get that number of [A] [B] rows returned for each [A].PK_ID value.

Assuming I'm right I'd do something like this,

```
SELECT [A].PK_ID, [B].Surname, [B].Firstname
  FROM [dbo].[client] [A]

 INNER JOIN [dbo].[contact] [B]
    ON [B].FK_Client = [A].PK_ID
   AND [A].Type = 22

 WHERE [A].PK_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT [C].FK_Client
                       FROM [dbo].[ad] [C]

                      INNER JOIN [dbo].[table_ad_attribute] [D]
                         ON [D].FK_ad = [C].PK_ID 
                        AND [D].FK_attribute = 42)
```

Your [C] -> [D] join identifies the [A].PK_ID values you're interested in so I've put that into a subquery which I then use in a WHERE clause for your [A] -> [B] join.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you join all these tables at all? It seems you want to select clients with their contacts and restrict this somehow. So join clients and contacts and put your criteria in the `WHERE` clause. This gets you all type 22 clients that have a 42 ad with their contacts:

```
select cl.pk_id, co.surname, co.firstname
from dbo.client cl
join dbo.contact co on co.fk_client = cl.pk_id
where cl.type = 22
and cl.pk_id in
(
  select fk_client
  from dbo.ad
  where pk_id in (select fk_ad from dbo.table_ad_attribute where fk_attribute = 42)
);
```